# What sections are required for a usable ELF executable?

Tags: elf, executable-format, sections

I'm creating an ELF executable file and I need to know what sections are required by the operating system in order to load and execute it.

> Details:
>
> ```
> OS:               Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit)
> Kernel version:   2.6.32-24
> Architecture:     i386
> ```

I realize that the following would probably be necessary:

- .text
- .symtab
- .rel.text

Are there others?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to try systematically stripping sections from an ELF file generated by GCC.

I was able to remove many of the sections, but these could not be removed and have the executable still execute without a segmentation fault:

```
.dynsym
.dynstr
.gnu.version_r
.rel.plt
.init
.plt
.text
.fini
.ctors
.dtors
.dynamic
.got.plt
.data
.strtab
```